# How do I rename my local git repository

Tags: eclipse, egit

I've renamed my remote repository and created a new local repository from it. How do I change it within EGit in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

Previous answer list below also has issues. The only solution appears to be:

1. Backup .project, etc. files
2. Delete existing project
3. Import existing local git repository as a "general project"
4. Put backed up files into the new project
5. Restart Eclipse

---

Rename, per se, is not the actual operation -- changing repository is the correct mindset to solving the problem according to a coworker.

1. Select 'Team->Disconnect'
2. Select 'Team->Share' On 'Share Project' dialog
3. Select Git and click Next
4. Unselect 'Use or create repository in parent folder of project'
5. Select the new local repository
6. Checkbox the project name showing correct current location and target location
7. Click 'Finish'

Eclipse will move existing files from previous local repository to the new local repository.

Answer (score 1):

I just renamed a repository.  I use [LiClipse](http://www.liclipse.com/), an Eclipse variant which includes EGit.  I believe there is no way to do this operation with the EGit UI. Here's how I did it outside of EGit and Eclipse, without confusing them.

1. In the Git perspective, right-click on the repo, and select *Remove repository from view...* from the pop-up menu.
2. A dialogue box offers to delete the repository from the workspace. I interpreted this to mean, delete the repo directory and everything in it from my disk. Press the "No" button.
3. In the programming language-specific perspective (PyDev, in my case), right-click on the project, and select *Delete...* from the pop-up menu.
4. A confirmation dialogue box appears. In this case, I interpret it as just confirming that I want to remove the project's entry from the project list in that perspective. There is a checkbox, "Delete this project from workspace?". Leave that checkbox unchecked. Press the "Yes" button to confirm.
5. In the finder or command-line, find the repository directory, and change the directory name to the new name.
6. Return to Eclipse, and the Git perspective.
7. Select menu item, *File... Open projects from file system...*. (There is also a small icon with a "+", above the projects list, with tooltip "Add an existing local Git repository to this view". I believe it is different but equivalent.)  A dialogue box appears.
8. Select the (renamed) repository directory. Click *Next* or *Finish* to complete the wizard. The Repository appears in the list of Git repositories in EGit.
9. Return to the programming language-specific perspective appropriate for that repository.
10. Select menu item, *File... Open projects from file system...*. A dialogue box appears.
11. Select the (renamed) repository directory. Click *Next* or *Finish* to complete the wizard. The Repository appears in the list of Git repositories in that language-specific perspective.

The project-specific Eclipse settings appear to be stashed away in a file `.project` within the repository, so they are not modified by the rename happening overhead.